# how to get the long & lat value of four corners in the mapview in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, overlayitem

i working on map view. i want to put overlay item  on the map view.  that overlay items are all depends on currently showing map view and zoom level. how to get current map view's longitude and latitude of that four corner and how to analyze how many overlay item inside it. also we have to check thee zoom level.Any Idea? how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have to use

```
mapview.getProjection().frompixel(intx, int y)
```

For the 4 corners of your screen (you can get their coordinates by getwidth and getheight on your mapView, and starting with (0,0), (getwidth(),0), (0,getheight()) and (getwidth(), getheight())

This will give you 4 geopoints from which you can extract latitude and longitude

Comment: You're welcome, actually I had no idea of the answer of the answer when I saw your question but it triggered my interest and I looked for it

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the `google-play-services` library and the `SupportMapFragment` in particular.

`this.getMap()` will give you the instance of `GoogleMap` (which wraps `MapView`)

Then just:

`map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();`

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
GeoPoint topLeft = proj.fromPixels(0, 0);

GeoPoint bottomRight = proj.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth()-1, mapView.getHeight()-1);

double topLat = topLeft.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double topLon = topLeft.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
double bottomLat = bottomRight.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double bottomLon = bottomRight.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
```

Hope it helps!